# Active tab from dropdown menu does not jump to content

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have want to open and jump to tab content by clicking dropdown menu item but my code only open the tab content without jumping and doesn't active tablist.

My dropdown menu code is

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Category<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="categorydd">
<li><a href="#fday" data-toggle="tab">First Day</a></li>
<li><a href="#sday" data-toggle="tab">Second Day</a></li>
<li><a href="#tday" data-toggle="tab">Third Day</a>
</ul>
```

The Tablist is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="active"><a href="#fday" aria-controls="fday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FIRST DAY</a></li>
<li><a href="#sday" aria-controls="sday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SECOND DAY</a></li>
<li><a href="#tday" aria-controls="tday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">THIRD DAY</a></li>
</ul>
```

and tab content are

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="fday">
.....
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="sday">
....
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tday">
....
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $('#categorydd a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $($(this).attr('href').tab('show')
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Would you post your JS code?

Comment: My JS code is not actually working but here it is 
     <script> 
    $('#categorydd a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $($(this).attr('href').tab('show')
    })
 </script>